# Is it possible to send message from electron IpcRenderer to html iframe inside a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, postmessage

I'm loading an external website URL in the browser window. The website has an HTML iframe inside it.

I am able to send a message from main to renderer using a preload.js file. From my website, I can send messages to the main.js, but is it possible to send a message to the iframe from main.js?

In preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer, webContents } = require('electron')

window.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {}) //listening to message from main.js

ipcRenderer.on('okStorage', (event, ...args) => {window.postMessage(args, '*')}) //sending message to the webpage right?
```

In Main.js:

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('okStorage', "someMessage")
```

✌

Comment: You've already written the code... so have you tried it? If not, then why are you asking without having tried it?

Comment: I have tried it and I'm able to get messages from the HTML iframe in the website to main.js. But not from main.js to the html iframe inside the webpage.